# Visual Web Developer (Express): Setting Document Root for Dev Environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-web-developer, server-configuration

I'm developing a site in Visual Web Dev Express, and when I run/debug, I'd like to be able to set my application's document root so that I can use safer paths, like "/css/style.css' instead of "css/style.css". How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Click on the web site node in the solution explorer.
- Press F4 to see the properties window.
- Change the virtual path from **/projectname** to **/**

Bear in mind that this has an impact on how you expect the application/web site to be deployed. If it is ever used outside the root of a web server, the URL paths will be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for the virtual path field in the properties window but haven't been able to find it... it only shows me the following options

- aperture directory URL
- complete access route
- policy file
- port
- use dynamic port

Do you know of some place else where I could find the Virtual Path field?

Answer (score 0):

Select the "Web" tab and it's in the Servers section